# Unable to Install Managed Package Get Error: Missing Organization Feature: DandBEnterprise

Tags: managed-package, package, enterprise

I am migrating our company's metadata from our development org into our enterpirse org using a managed package. However, whenenver I try to install the package in my enterprise org I get the following error.

Missing Organization Feature: DandBEnterprise

From what I understand I need to either enable DandBEnterprise in the enterprise org or disable it in the development org. I have looked everywhere but I am unable to find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be an issue because you might have added D&B fields in your package for account or contact records .

If your package is not managed released you can get rid off this fields from the package .I would get away these fields from the development org and get rid of dependency

Additionally double check these boxes are unchecked

[image]

Also check if you have included the fields in the page layout or any other metadata .Using an eclipse IDE would be helpful to pull package metadata and run a search against it

Comment: My package is manged released and i'm not able to see any d&b fields in my package

Comment: Well there is a dependency somewhere thats created .I would take all metadata from your package code and search for the D&B using IDE

Comment: I think I found the issue. I accidentally added a D&B page layout to the released packed. However I am not able to remove it. I tried to downgrade to a beta version but everything is still locked down. What should I do??!!

Comment: Raise a case with support .They can help you here. The other option is to move your package to a different org and generate new package .I am adding page layout to answer .In general my answer is correct so feel free to upvote or add your own answer